# Changes in RPD not showing up in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, repository, oracle12c, obiee

My question is this. I am using OBIEE 12c and recently I changed the .rpd file in offline mode and then uploaded it to the server. However I dont see my changes there.

Interesting is the fact that when I open the .rpd in online mode in Admin tool, which shows the current rpd in OBIEE, I see my changes. I tried editing in online or offline modes, changed the names of rpds, restarted the server, but nothing helped. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT.. It was my fault partially. I was making changes in BMM layer and I was pretty sure that my changes will be automatically updated in Presentation layer(it was when I checked with several aggregations), however in this case, my changes did not reflected in Presentation layer. Why is like this?

P.S. I was modifying hierarchies if important